# Работа веток в Git

Tags: git, git-branch

Пожалуйста, объясните простым языком, как работают ветки в Git.

Какая их основная задача?

Comment: я же написал объясните простым языком, если не хочешь объяснять не нужно было откликаться

Comment: А что есть "простым языком"? Вот те, кто писал статьи в интернете и видео снимал - наверняка думали, что объясняли простым языком, а не для профессоров с пятью степенями, не так ли? Так каков критерий простоты и почему думаешь, что тут будет чем-то отличаться от того, что уже видел?

Comment: может быть вы для начала опишите как вы поняли, а вас поправят?

Comment: я понял что в репозитории можно создавать ветки, в этих ветках можно добавлять файлы с кодом, и можно создавать несколько веток, но не понимаю, что такое ветка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В гите ветка - это ссылка на коммит. Она нужна для того, чтобы находить коммит, которым оканчивается цепочка изменений в файлах. Каждый коммит содержит какие-то изменения в файлах и ссылку на предыдущий. Эти изменения и ссылка фиксированы. Ветка же не содержит никаких данных, только ссылку на произвольный коммит.
На картинке серые кружки со стрелками - это коммиты, а синие прямоугольники со стрелками - ветки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда выполняется команда `git checkout <branch>` то по названию ветки находится коммит и затем, применяя изменения в файлах по цепочке коммитов вплоть до этого, состояние файлов приводится к тому, которое было, когда создали коммит, на который указывает ветка. Причем заметьте, что на картинке на коммит 3df ничего не ссылается, соответственно файлы нельзя просто так привести к состоянию, соответствующему этому коммиту.

Когда выполняется команда `git commit`, то создается новый коммит в который записываются изменения в файлах и ссылка на текущий коммит, а текущая ветка начинает указывать на этот новый коммит.

Также следует заметить, что терминология в гите радикально отличается от других VCS, прежде всего от mercurial, где под термином "ветка" подразумевается другое.

Comment: Нет, ветка - это не ссылка. Вот `tag` - это ссылка. Ветка это что-то большее, от корня до листьев.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Нет, это именно ссылка. Чем-то большим, от корня до листьев, она является как раз в вышеупомянутом mercurial. Это кстати одна из сильных сторон mercurial, выгодно отличающая его от git. `tag` в git это фактический аналог ветки, только без возможности менять коммит, на который она ссылается.

Comment: Да ветка - это ссылка, но с дополнительными способностями менять свой указатель при разных командах. У `tag` скрытых способностей нет, это просто ссылка на отдельный коммит. Ветка создана именно для удобства автоматического перенаправления ссылки на последний рабочий коммит. Наверное, вопрос был в том, зачем ветки вообще нужны?

Comment: @AlexGlebe Собственно на вопрос "зачем ветки вообще нужны" я дал исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, tag — фиксированный указатель на коммит, а branch — плавающий указатель на коммит. вот и вся **техническая** между ними разница.

Comment: `применяя изменения в файлах по цепочке коммитов` — тут немножко тонко-технически неверно. файлы восстанавливаются по содержимому объектов типа tree, а не типа commit. это означает, что при команде checkout не просматриваются цепочки коммитов, а извлекается объект типа tree (который может содержать как файлы, так и ссылки на другие объекты типа tree) и, рекурсивно, все остальные объекты типа tree.

Answer (score -2):

Ветка - это "копия" проекта, в которой происходит разработка чего-либо. Разработка окончена и протестирована? Слили в основную ветку.
Коммиты - типо, бекапов, после определенных изменений в проекте.
Это если очень кратко.
Неплохая статья, даже коротенький курс по Git - [Урок 3. Ветвление](https://smartiqa.ru/courses/git/lesson-3)

> работать с Git'ом только через Git Bash

Если работаешь в VSC можно через встроенный терминал, либо (что удобнее) через "Встроенную систему управления версиями".
Посмотри также в сторону приложения GitHub Desktop.

Comment: ветка - это не копия проекта

Comment: Вот worktree - это, скорее, копия.

Comment: Да, технически Вы правы, но "это если очень кратко".

Comment: ну как-то это ты совсем не простым языком объяснил :D

Comment: Вам кстати тоже стоит присоединиться к спрашивающему вопрос, так как представление о том, что такое ветки у вас крайне смутное. И у тех, кто делал урок по ссылке - тоже.

Comment: @user7860670 по-моему, представление о ветках тут ни при чем. Ответ должен быть не только правильным, но и понятным. В этом плане этот ответ, хоть и не идеален, но ближе к тому, который будет понятен вопрошающему. Ваш ответ безусловно правильный в техническом плане, но совсем не отвечает на главный вопрос - "зачем нужны ветки".

Comment: @RomanKonoval Собственно на вопрос "зачем ветки вообще нужны" я дал исчерпывающий ответ. А вот в этом ответе не поясняется, ни что такое ветка, ни ни для чего они нужны.